# UploadCollection upload attachment from oData gives Cannot read property 'bindItems'

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I try to uploading attachment from oData service for a Fiori application using UploadCollection inside a fragment.

Fragment Code:

```html
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m"
 xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
 <UploadCollection id="UploadCollection" maximumFilenameLength="55" multiple="true" change="onChange" fileDeleted="onFileDeleted"
  fileRenamed="onFileRenamed" fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" items="{/DataAttachment}" typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch"
  uploadComplete="onUploadComplete">
  <items>
   <UploadCollectionItem contributor="{contributor}" documentId="{documentId}" fileName="{fileName}" fileSize="{fileSize}"
    mimeType="{mimeType}" thumbnailUrl="{thumbnailUrl}" uploadedDate="{uploadedDate}" enableEdit="{enableEdit}" enableDelete="{enableDelete}"/>
  </items>
 </UploadCollection>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Detail code:

```html
<IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://attachment" iconColor="Neutral" design="Horizontal" text="Attachment" key="Attachment">
      <content>
       <core:Fragment id="AttachmentFrag"  fragmentName="ztravel.view.Attachment" type="XML"/>
      </content>
</IconTabFilter>
```

controller Detail code:

```js
   var sEntityPath = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSERVICE/", true);

   // this.setModel(oViewModel);

   // this.getView().bindElement("/DataAttachment");
   
   var oView = this.getView();
   
   // oView.bindElement(sEntityPath);
   // update list binding
   var sAttach = sEntityPath + "/DataAttachment";
   

   var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.UploadCollectionItem({
    documentId: "{Pernr}",
    fileName: "{Reinr}",
    mimeType: "{ImMimeType}",
    thumbnailUrl: "",
    // url: {
    //  parts: [{
    //   path: 'ImImgEqui'
    //  }, {
    //   path: 'ImIdEqui'
    //  }],
    //  formatter: function(idimg, idequi) { 
    //   return oView.getModel().sServiceUrl + "/AttachmentsSet(ImImgEqui='" + idimg + "',ImIdEqui='" + idequi + "')/$value";
    //  }
    // },

    enableEdit: false,
    enableDelete: false,
    visibleDelete: false,
    visibleEdit: false,
    statuses: new sap.m.ObjectStatus({
     title: "Uploaded On",
     text: {
      parts: [{
       path: 'ImDatum'
      }],
      formatter: function(sValue) {
       if (sValue) {
        var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
         pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy"
        });
        return oDateFormat.format(new Date(sValue));

       } else {
        return sValue;
       }
      }
     }
    })

   });
   
  // var fragmentId = this.getView().createId("AttachmentFrag");
     //       var tab = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(fragmentId, "UploadCollection");
       //     tab.bindItems({
   // path: sAttach,
   // template: oItemTemplate
   //});
   
   sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("AttachmentFrag", "UploadCollection").bindItems({
   path: sAttach,
   template: oItemTemplate
   });
```

Console give me this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindItems' of undefined

on the final part of detail controller code:
sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("AttachmentFrag", "UploadCollection").bindItems({....

Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks all,

Mav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(this.getView().createId("AttachmentFrag"), "UploadCollection")
```

Comment: Thanks Andrii, your solutions work fine to solve the error.
Probably I've done some other error, because I can't see the attachment.
The console give this error:
http://localhost:57681/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSERVICE/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

can you know where I wrong?

Comment: Which backend do you use? Where it is located? Can you provide the request path form the network tab (in developer tools) to which the file is going to be uploaded?

Comment: The service is done in ECC Gateway, the path is:
http://domainclient.org:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSERVICE/DataAttach
do you mean this?

if I launch it in the browser I see the data, so I think the back-end service haven't problem

Comment: Do you use csrf tokens for the odata calls?

Comment: Yes I use it! Now I solve the problem. My error was in the attachment's fragment, because I leaved the redefinition of items inside.
Now I have problem in the action definition, but I try to solve.
Thanks Andrii for your help, it was greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your console error message, does it also say which method is not allowed (maybe “Post”)?
As mentioned before, what is the request/method shown in the “Network” tab (right next to “Console” tab)?
Is it correct that it tries to call your “ZSERVICE” on “localhost:57681” while the service points to “domainclient.org:8000” ?

What happens, if you test your service in the backend using transaction “/n/IWFND/GW_CLIENT”?

Comment: Thanks for your indication, anyway the error was in the mimeType parameter (I wrong the name) and because I try to create also in the view that I triyng to create in the controller.